# best practices to reduce the ram load on the server

Tags: php, mysql, cpanel, vps

I recently saw stats on my vps dashboard. but I wonder why the level of use in RAM so much, when the number of visitors have not boming.

**following product details:**

```
OS : CentOS 7 64bit
CPU Cores count : 3
Total CPU(s) speed : 4800Mhz
Memory : 2 GB
```

The number of online visitors an average of 30 people. this takes up about 50% of the amount of Memory available. so it can be estimated if the number of online visitors reached 60 people, then the use of RAM is overloaded.

Is this at a reasonable level? or I need to set up a strategy to prevent the site from being down?

Additional information: I build a site NOT from wordpress or anything else. all suggestions and opinions are greatly awaited, thank you.

Comment: way to broad: "Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question."

Answer (score -1):

The subject is too broad.

- Manage your cache
- Make use of virtual memory
- Use pointers and references when programming: Even if you are not using C++, you still can call large objects and files by reference.
- kill unused processes
- Uninstall unnecessary applications.  This includes starting up applications if you know what you are doing.
- Do not open many windows at once
- prefer text and command utilities rather than graphical interfaces.